# Realtime Random in cmd (at console not batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

when I execute this :

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do @(echo %random%)
```

it prints :

```
14325
14325
14325
14325
14325
```

so I look through stack_overflow then found solution
It's

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    echo %random% !random!
)
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
15345
3423
233
23212
41222
```

This is works well in batch but not console

console can't deal with !random!

.. What can I do?

Comment: `cmd /?` shows the solution (see `/V` parameter)

Comment: Your 2nd sample output cannot result from your 2nd code example... please correct...

Comment: Thx @Stephan your solution works well _italic_222

Answer (score 0):

Within a batch file you can use `call echo %%RANDOM%%` instead of `echo !RANDOM!`. But that does not work on the command line. Instead you must use `call echo %^RANDOM%`. On the first pass, the caret is considered part of the name, the variable doesn't exist, so nothing is expanded, and the percents remain. The first pass consumes the caret, so the second pass properly expands `%RANDOM%`.

```
for /l %N in (1 1 5) do @call echo %^random%
```

The other option is to use `cmd /v:on` to issue the command in a new process with delayed expansion enabled.

```
cmd /v:on /c for /l %N in (1 1 5) do @echo !random!
```